# How to read multiple excel file and write in one excel file using Script (batch file)?

Tags: excel, batch-file

I want to read multiple excel file and write to one excel file using Script. is it possible with batch files?
more specifically, i want to pass the folder name(container of multiple excel files) in a script and want the result (or the output excel file)...

Comment: rather with powershell , vbscript or jscript....

Comment: i've made some changes in my description to make it more specific... and please share your suggestion about how can i solve the issue with any other script like powershell  ...

Comment: Searching this site for `[powershell][excel]` or `[vbscript][excel]` should provide you with tons of examples for handling Excel in either language. Please try your hands on it first and come back when you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread discussed about merging excel files here: [Merge many excel files into one excel files](http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/63612-merge-many-excel-files-into-one-excel-files.html)